# Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that has a superclass vehicle and has 3 classes inheriting from it car,truck,minibus I need to take instances of the classes and display them in a listbox on my main form 'FrmHire' I have a class called fleet for this.

I keep getting this error,

> Cannot implicitly convert type App1.Vehicle to App1.Car. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
private void lstFleet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * This method is used to control the list box
         * It is called when a row is selected by the user, it then displays frmCar
         * with the car details
         */ 
        if (lstFleet.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            int index = lstFleet.SelectedIndex;
            Car myCar = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
            FrmCar carGui = new FrmCar();
            carGui.car = myCar;
            carGui.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you point to the line that throws an error?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your list might contain Cars, Trucks or Minibusses, you can assume that you can take the ElementAt(index) and cast it to Car, can you?

Presumably you get back a Vehicle from the ElementAt(index), and if you know that it will be a car then you can explicitly cast it to Car, but the implicit cast that you have here is causing this issue.

So, you either need (if you know for sure they're all Car instances and anything else is an exception)...

```
Car myCar = (Car)myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
```

... or you need to deal with this as a Vehicle...

```
Vehicle myVehicle = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
```

If you want to test whether the item is a Car (and do something different if not) then this...

```
Car myCar = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index) as Car;
if (myCar != null)
{
    // it was a car
}
```

Comment: the first one works but in the listbox it throws in the name of the solution then a .then car instead of Car:? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of myFleet.fleet? I suspect it is a collection of Vehicle's and you're trying to assign one to a Car.

Answer (score 0):

```
Car myCar = (Car)myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
```

This will throw an exception if `myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);` is not a `Car`. To check if it is a `Car` you can do `if (myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index) is Car) {...}`. But the best is to use a `List<Car>` instead of `List<Vehicle>` if you're only going to store Cars in it.

Comment: This might throw. I'd prefer myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index) as Car so I can check myCar for null.

Comment: Hi has removed the error but in my text box it says 'WindowsApplication1.Car' apose to 'Car:  which I have it should do....

Comment: @bettsy583, on what line? Is that on the `carGui.car = myCar;` line now?

Comment: @bettsy583: Are you assinging a property of a vehicle to your textbox? Sounds like you're using ToString() which by default will show the class name.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, not a text box I am trying to have a superclass of vehicle, with truck car minibus in heriting from it, I then have forms to enter details about each type of vehicle then I want to push the close button on each form and then it add the contents to a list box on the main form.

Comment: Create a property on your class that gives the name of the vehicle (Car, Truck, etc.) and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Car myCar = (Car)myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
```

Comment: This works but it takes the name of the solution and displays it in the listbox.....